# Finding the index of an intersection of 2 subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

If two subgroups of a finite abelian group G have the same index 3 in G, what is the index of their intersection in G??

Comment: Have you tried some example cases to get an idea of what might happen? What will happen, if $G=\Bbb{Z}_3\oplus\Bbb{Z}_3$? What's your guess? What results have you covered recently? We would like to hear that for otherwise there is the danger that the answers won't teach you anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t tell, but you know at least that it is a multiple of $3$.

In $S_3$, take $H_1 = 〈(1~2)〉$ and $H_2 = 〈(1~3)〉$. Then $[S_3 : H_1] = 3 = [S_3 : H_2]$. As $H_1 ∩ H_2 = 1$, the index of their intersection is $6$. Of course, the index of $H_1 = H_1 ∩ H_1$ in $S_3$ is still $3$.

Here’s a proof that the index of $H_1 ∩ H_2$ is a multiple of the least common multiple of the respective indices of $H_1$ and $H_2$ in a group $G$:

It follows from Lagrange: As $|H_1 ∩ H_2|$ divides both $|H_1|$ and $|H_2|$, both $[G : H_1] = \frac{|G|}{|H_1|}$ and $[G : H_2] = \frac{|G|}{|H_2|}$ divide $[G : H_1 ∩ H_2] = \frac{|G|}{|H_1 ∩ H_2|}$, so the latter is a common multiple of the former both.

Comment: Presumably the subgroups are distinct in OP's question, in which case we can tell.

Comment: @k.stm. thank you... I guessed so... now it seems my guess turns out right

Comment: +1, because I like this, and it was the first thought that came to my mind as well. But the OP seems to restrict themself to **abelian subgroups**. Perhaps surprisingly that makes a difference (and the answer is ___, I will undelete my answer, when/if we hear a bit of context from the OP).